# Is everything a Malkavian sees or does automatically added to the Malkavian Madness Network?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I've been reading up on the Malkavian and their Madness Network, but it isn't entirely clear to me exactly what gets "uploaded" into it and what does not. Is it recording 24/7, or does the Malkavian have a say in what does or does not get added to the MMN?

I'd prefer answers derived from the 20th anniversary books, but if they don't state this I also accept answers based on earlier editions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most recent description of the Madness Network comes from V20's **Lore of the Clans**. In that work, on page 139, it's suggested that everything (more or less) is heard by the slumbering mind of Malkav himself. Then, that information is bounced off the Elders of the clan and then retransmitted in a giant game of Telephone so that the knowledge has a chance to be warped, garbled, or made irrelevant in transit — except when it's relevant to you or the game you're in. Using the network proactively is covered in "Malkavian Time" on page 146.